# feign client response does not retrive cookie named sessionid while postman does

Tags: java, django, session, token, feign

I have to connect to django web application using feign client.

First, i checked the flow in postman.

**In postman**

1. I'm using GET on myapp/accounts/login/?next=/ **and retrive csrftoken** as entry Set-Cookie in response headers
2. I'm using POST on myapp/accounts/login/?next=/ with body as x-www-form-urlencoded

```
"username=login&password=password&csrfmiddlewaretoken=token&next=/"
```

and **retrive NEW csrftoken and sessionid** as entry in Set-Cookie. The response code is 302 (Found) so it's working fine

I need those two cookies to use as request headers with another endpoints

The problem is that i cannot reproduce the same in feign client which i have to use

1. The feign response from POST doesn't have second cookie (sessionId)
2. The csrftoken is not refreshed

I think i was trying almost everything : cookieinterceptor, turning off follow redirects in okhttp client, session interceptor in okhttp

My simple code looks like :

```
public class Main {
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_TEMPLATE = "username=%s&password=%s&csrfmiddlewaretoken=%s&next=/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RouteClient routeClient = Feign.builder()
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .logger(new CustomFeignLogger())
                .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                .target(RouteClient.class, DataInput.url);

        Response getResponse = routeClient.getToken();

        String cookie = extractCookie(getResponse);
        String token = extractToken(cookie);

        Response postResponse = routeClient.postDataWithParametersInBody(insertHeaderMap(token),
                insertBody(AUTHENTICATION_TEMPLATE, token));

        System.out.println(postResponse);

    }

    public static String insertBody(String template, String token) {
        return String.format(template, DataInput.username, DataInput.password, token);
    }

    public static String extractToken(String cookie) {
        return cookie.split("=")[1].split(";")[0];
    }

    public static Map<String, String> insertHeaderMap(String token) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        map.put("Cookie", "csrftoken="+token);
        return map;
    }

    public static String extractCookie(Response response) {
        return new ArrayList<>(response.headers().get("set-cookie")).get(0);
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows why i am not retriving the second cookie and the first cookie does not refresh?

The similar code for python works well

and retrives two cookies where the first one is refreshed

> <RequestsCookieJar [<Cookie csrftoken=ygfcLx...... for ......com/>,
> <Cookie sessionid=vtvo5cbe2cew... for ....com/>]>